# How do I continue my program after the "##"

Tags: mips

So I have made a program which allows users to put how many hello world that they want and after ## there is another function but that won't play out instead the program just closes.

```
        .data
n:      .space 4
msg:    .asciiz "Hello World"
prom1:  .asciiz "How many Hello World want to be printed: "
mychar1:.byte 'a'
out_string:   .asciiz "\nHello World\n"
prom:   .asciiz "Type a number: "
mychar: .byte 'm'
res:    .asciiz "Result is: "
nl:     .asciiz "\n"

        .text
main:   li $v0, 4
        la $a0, msg
        syscall

        li $v0, 4     # print str
        la $a0, nl    # at nl
        syscall
        li $v0, 4     # print str
        la $a0, nl    # at nl
        syscall
        
        li $v0, 4           
        la $a0, prom1       # Load address of first prompt
        syscall 

        li $v0, 5           # Read int from user
        syscall
        
        li $t1, 0       # Load 0 into $t1 for comparison
        move $t0, $v0       # Move the user input to $t0

loop:
        beq  $t1, $t0, end  # Break If Equal: branch to 'end' when $t1 == $t2
        li $v0, 4       
        la $a0, out_string  # Load address of output string
        syscall
        add $t1, $t1, 1     # Increment $t1
        j loop          # Jump back up to loop
        
end:
        li $v0, 10      # Load syscall 10 to indicate end of program
        syscall 


##


        li $v0, 4     # print str
        la $a0, nl    # at nl
        syscall
        
        li $v0, 4     # print str
        la $a0, prom  # at prom
        syscall

        li $v0, 5     # read int
        syscall
        sw $v0, n     # store in n

        li $v0, 4     # print str
        la $a0, res   # at res
        syscall

        li $v0, 1     # print int
        lw $t0, n          # n
        sub $t1, $t0, 1    # n-1
        mul $t0, $t0, $t1  # *
        sra $a0, $t0, 1    # /2
        syscall


        li $v0, 4     # print str
        la $a0, nl    # at nl
        syscall


        li $v0, 4     # print str
        la $a0, nl    # at nl
        syscall

        li $v0, 10    # exit
        syscall
```

Comment: Your answer has some formatting problems. Try to improve that. Use `\`` brackets for paths and code fragments. To highlight apps' names or interface, use a **bold** (`**` brackets) or *italic* (`*` brackets) font. To start from a new line use *double space* at the end of the line - the question'll be way more clear than using *Enter* everywhere. Adding some `:` would be nice too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this spot here

```
end:
            li $v0, 10      # Load syscall 10 to indicate end of program
            syscall
```

You are calling a syscall with 10 in the $v0 register.
This tells the computer to stop the program. So in this case you are just stopping the program before the rest of the code is executed.

Instead you could do this

```
loop:
        beq  $t1, $t0, endloop  
        li $v0, 4       
        la $a0, out_string  # Load address of output string
        syscall
        add $t1, $t1, 1     # Increment $t1
        j loop          # Jump back up to loop

endloop:
        # Put rest of code here
```

This is just the way to end the loop and continue.

Then at the end of the program you can put the syscall 10

Comment: Thank you so much again! Its actually my first day today learning MIPS so it can be quite confusing! Upvoted and and accepted again~